# Como criar uma lista para salvar inúmeros plots gerados pela minha função no R?

Tags: r, lista, data.frame

Boa noite caros amigos!

Criei um script que gera várias pirâmides etárias simultaneamente. No caso, a grande vantagem é gerar centenas, ou até milhares de pirâmides em poucos minutos. Estou precisando de ajuda para indexar os Plots gerados (pirâmides) para conseguir acessá-las depois. O ideal seria indexar pelo Nome da localidade.

Enfim, vou compartilhar meu script que faz 646 pirâmides para todas as cidades do Estado de SP.

Bom, se vocês rodarem esse código com o banco de dados que utilizei verão que ele funciona e gera todas pirâmides, porém, como disse no inicio preciso de alguma dica para conseguir indexar esse tanto de Plot gerado.... Obrigado.

````
library(plotrix)
library(GetoptLong)
library(tidyverse)


#Importando base de dados com valores absolutos estimados para 2020 
#produzidos pela Funda??o SEADE 

p_etarias_raw <-
  read.csv2(
    "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\projetos\\piramides_etarias\\p_etarias_estado_sp.csv",
    encoding = "windows-1250",
    sep = ";",
    dec = ",",
    header = TRUE)

view(p_etarias_raw)


p_etarias <- p_etarias_raw[,2:647]



dataset_length <- length(names(p_etarias))

for (a in 2:dataset_length) {
  p_etarias[2,a] <- (p_etarias[2,a]/sum(p_etarias[1,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[3,a] <- (p_etarias[3,a]/sum(p_etarias[1,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[4,a] <- (p_etarias[4,a]/sum(p_etarias[1,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[5,a] <- (p_etarias[5,a]/sum(p_etarias[1,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[6,a] <- (p_etarias[6,a]/sum(p_etarias[1,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[7,a] <- (p_etarias[7,a]/sum(p_etarias[1,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[8,a] <- (p_etarias[8,a]/sum(p_etarias[1,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[9,a] <- (p_etarias[9,a]/sum(p_etarias[1,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[10,a] <- (p_etarias[10,a]/sum(p_etarias[1,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[11,a] <- (p_etarias[11,a]/sum(p_etarias[1,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[12,a] <- (p_etarias[12,a]/sum(p_etarias[1,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[13,a] <- (p_etarias[13,a]/sum(p_etarias[1,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[14,a] <- (p_etarias[14,a]/sum(p_etarias[1,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[15,a] <- (p_etarias[15,a]/sum(p_etarias[1,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[16,a] <- (p_etarias[17,a]/sum(p_etarias[1,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[17,a] <- (p_etarias[17,a]/sum(p_etarias[1,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[19,a] <- (p_etarias[19,a]/sum(p_etarias[18,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[20,a] <- (p_etarias[20,a]/sum(p_etarias[18,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[21,a] <- (p_etarias[21,a]/sum(p_etarias[18,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[22,a] <- (p_etarias[22,a]/sum(p_etarias[18,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[23,a] <- (p_etarias[23,a]/sum(p_etarias[18,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[24,a] <- (p_etarias[24,a]/sum(p_etarias[18,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[25,a] <- (p_etarias[25,a]/sum(p_etarias[18,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[26,a] <- (p_etarias[26,a]/sum(p_etarias[18,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[27,a] <- (p_etarias[27,a]/sum(p_etarias[18,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[28,a] <- (p_etarias[28,a]/sum(p_etarias[18,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[29,a] <- (p_etarias[29,a]/sum(p_etarias[18,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[30,a] <- (p_etarias[30,a]/sum(p_etarias[18,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[31,a] <- (p_etarias[31,a]/sum(p_etarias[18,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[32,a] <- (p_etarias[32,a]/sum(p_etarias[18,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[33,a] <- (p_etarias[33,a]/sum(p_etarias[18,a]) * 100)
  p_etarias[34,a] <- (p_etarias[34,a]/sum(p_etarias[18,a]) * 100)
}


agelabels <- c(
  "0-4",
  "5-9",
  "10-14",
  "15-19",
  "20-24",
  "25-29",
  "30-34",
  "35-39",
  "40-44",
  "45-49",
  "50-54",
  "55-59",
  "60-64",
  "65-69",
  "70-74",
  "75+"
)

#Definindo as cores das barras
mcol <- color.id('#5882FA')
fcol <- color.id('#FE2E2E')



for (i in 2:dataset_length) {
  
  xy.pop <- c(p_etarias[2:17, i])
  xx.pop <- c(p_etarias[19:34, i])
  
  municipality_name = names(p_etarias[i])
  
  piramide1 <- par(
    mar = pyramid.plot(
      xy.pop,
      xx.pop,
      labels = agelabels,
      main = qq("Pirâmide Etária @{municipality_name}"),
      lxcol = mcol,
      rxcol = fcol,
      gap = 1.3,
      show.values = FALSE,
      top.labels = c("Masc", "Idade", "Fem"),
      ndig = 3,
    )
  )
  
}```
````

Comment: Lucca, boa noite! Consegue disponibilizar o arquivo: p_etarias_estado_sp.csv? Abraço

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vou usar um exemplo genérico, para a resposta ser útil para o maior número possível de usuários. No caso, gerar uma lista com os box plots de cada coluna de um *data.frame*.

```
# Dados de exemplo
dados <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10))
names(dados) <- LETTERS[1:10]
```

Para armazenar gráficos em objetos, existe a função `recordPlot`. Ela funciona para gráficos gerados via `graphics` e `grid` (então não serve, por exemplo, para gráficos gerados por ggplot2).

Crie uma lista vazia para receber os gráficos e use um *loop* para atualizar:

```
plot.list <- vector("list", ncol(dados))
names(plot.list) <- names(dados)
# Poderia usar simplesmente `plot.list <- NULL', mas é uma boa prática já criar o objeto com o tamanho final.

for (id in names(dados)) {
  plot.new()
  boxplot(dados[[id]], main = paste("Boxplot da coluna", id))
  plot.list[id] <- list(recordPlot())
}
```

Ou, para evitar o uso de *loop* (uma boa prática em R), coloque o código que gera o gráfico em uma função e use `lapply`:

```
plot.bp <- function(j) {
  plot.new()
  boxplot(dados[[j]], main = paste("Boxplot da coluna", names(dados)[j]))
  recordPlot()
}

plot.list <- lapply(seq(ncol(dados)), plot.bp)
names(plot.list) <- names(dados)
```

Para exibir, por exemplo, o *plot* da variável B:

```
plot.list["B"]
# ou
plot.list$B
```